# Convert exisiting CentOS install to a LiveCD

Tags: centos

I would like to create an image of my existing CentOS from hard drive to a livecd.

I don't want to customize an installation cd, because I have many installed software which does not have RPM's.

I kind of know how to do it Debian, but I am clueless in CentOS.

Can someone help with a starting point(s)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK ...
I hate answering my own questions :-) but here is what I found out ...

the script [livecd-creator](https://github.com/livecd-tools/livecd-tools) from the live-tools, has too very appealing options which are suppressed when calling the script with -h flag. 
I had to dig into the python code to find it ...

if you call the script with the option --shell, you will get a shell, so you could play and customize your cd - this is a chrooted shell..., before it is created...:

Therefore, to create a live-cd based on your system:

customize the following file:
https://projects.centos.org/trac/livecd/browser/trunk/CentOS5/centos-livecd-minimal.ks?format=raw

add all your repositories, get a list of your packages from your system - don't forget vim and ssh. call the script like this:

```
LANG=C livecd-creator --config=centos-livecd-minimal.ks -f <YourCDNAME> --shell
```

this will give you a shell to play with:

edit all the files you want, if you have another server you can copy before hand all your configuration files, and then scp them from that server into your chroot.

when you finish type exit, this will pack your system into a livecd ...

if you are just testing and you want to save time, add the flag --skip-minimize for the above command.

Comment: The "based on your system" bit interests me. I need to create a live iso that contains only one script. Where do would I put the script so that it shows up on the live desktop? I guess I'll find out.

Comment: I updaded the link to the repository , check the instructions there.

Comment: https://projects.centos.org/trac/livecd/browser/trunk/CentOS5/centos-livecd-minimal.ks?format=raw <br> <br> is a dead link. Probably a good idea to remove it.